# Concatenation Values in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to concatenate the value from UITextField and value from button and display
them together in Objective-C? I'm trying but not getting it.

Comment: `NSMutableString* aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"String with one int %d", myInt];    // does not need to be released. Needs to be retained if you need to keep use it after the current function.
[aString appendFormat:@"... now has another int: %d", myInt];`

Comment: what the output you expect

Comment: Hope this helps you : NSString *strAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",textFeild.text,button.titleLabel.text];

Comment: perfect @Sujania

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
NSString *strConcate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",textFeild.text,button.titleLabel.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"String with two ints %d - %d", myInt, myInt];
NSLog(@"%@",aString);


NSString* aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"String with two ints %d - ... now has another int: %d", myInt, myInt];
NSLog(@"%@",aString);


//suppose - int one = 1; int two = 2; int three = 3
NSString *oneTwoThree = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d/%d", one, two, three];
NSLog(@"%@",oneTwoThree);


// suppose  
//UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] init];
//tf.text = "text field text"

//UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
//btn.titleLabel.text = "button text"

NSString* concatedString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", tf.text, btn.titleLabel.text];
NSLog(@"%@",concatedString); //result:  "text field text = button text"
```

Comment: I have a drop down list when we select item from that list it appears on the button.and have a text field. now i want to concatenate the value of textfield and that button value together to display. @Mobile App Developer

Comment: what do you mean by drop down ? Alert controller action sheet?

Comment: Last statement in my answer (NSString* concatedString) is doing same thing that you want. I think your problem is different. You are unable to get value for selected item or unable to get string value from button or textfiel Right?